# Creating a sqlite DB in Terminal, but connect to it in Java program (Mac)

Tags: java, sql, sqlite

I'm writing a basic program that handles customer information. I'm having some trouble with the Database part of it(I've never coded any with SQL or databases). My question is...
If I create a Sqlite Database in Terminal(b/c it seems easier than doing it in JAVA) and give it a Table, how can I then connect to that database in my java code? I have seen the Sqlite java tutorials on tutorialspoint.com, but can't seem to figure it out. Really having a hard time with this. I appreciate all input!
NOTE: I want to have my array called 'table' replaced with SQL calls to the database. 
Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Statement;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JSplitPane;
 import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;


public class Gui extends JFrame {   

 //Create the frame.
 public Gui() {

//General window commands
     Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
            int screenWidth = (int) screenSize.getWidth();
            int screenHeight = (int) screenSize.getHeight();
            final int programWidth = (int) ((double) screenWidth * 0.70);
            int programHeight = (int) ((double) screenHeight * 0.65);

     setBounds(screenWidth/9, screenHeight/10 /*or 90*/,programWidth, programHeight);
     setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


/*CREATING TAB NUM 1 CLIENTALE
        Table column names*/
            String[] columnNames = {"First Name", 
                                    "Last Name",
                                    "Car Year",     
                                    "Car Make", 
                                    "Mileage"};

        //Putting Data into the table
        //Will be replaced with SQL references
            Object[][] data = {
                    {"Colbey","Hatcher", new Integer(1997), 
                        "Mazda", new Integer(99999)},
                    {"Emilia","Ryan", new Integer(2012), 
                        "Honda", new Integer(10000)}};  


        //Table must be created after creation of Column Names and Data
            JTable table = new JTable(data, columnNames);

        //Create the scroll pane and add the table to it.
            JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
            table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);                        
//END OF TAB NUM 1 CLIENTALE


  //SETTING UP TABBED PANE & IMPLEMENTING CONTENT FROM ABOVE         
    JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
    tabbedPane.addTab("CUSTOMER TOTAL", scrollPane);
    //tabbedPane.addTab("NEW CUSTOMER", splitPane);

    //Adds everything above into the JFrame
    add(tabbedPane);
  //END OF TABE PANE SET UP     



}//end of constructor


public static void main(String[] args) {
EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
         try {
            Gui frame = new Gui();
            frame.setVisible(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
}//end of public static

}//end of jFrame
```